# Do I need a visa to visit the UK if I have Italian residence?

Tags: visas, uk, pakistani-citizens, italian-residents

I have Pakistani nationality and also an Italian permesso di soggiorno. What do I need in order to visit the UK?

Answer (score 3):

You need a visa for the UK, just like other Pakistani citizens.

The UK entry rules do not care about Italian residence permits (except in some cases of *transiting* through the UK, which is not the case when you want to *visit*).

(It also does not make any difference whether you're traveling by air or by train/ship).

Comment: A valid Italian permit might make it *easier* to get an UK visa since it demonstrates ties to your place of residence.